# Get Current Color Palette For Site

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to get the current Color Palette for the SharePoint Site IF it is not written in the design gallery (Composed Looks List) ?

I am using SharePoint Online and work with the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client Assembly.

Comment: hi, is an answer acceptable that uses the dev PnP Powershell tools? (Those tools are free, open source and recommended by Microsoft)

Comment: @RobertWagenaar - absolutely. It's very much acceptable.

Comment: @SharePointGuy I'm a bit puzzled by what you mean with 'IF it is not written in the design gallery (Composed Looks List). Can you elaborate on how you have set the Color Palette without editing a record in the Composed Looks List?